# Why gui has been installed during dist-upgrade, and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, x-server

I did a dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04LTS (Server, CL-only) to 18.04LTS then 20.04LTS.

During this operation, it seems some kind of gnome gui has been installed.

By verifying based on this article: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-check-if-gui-is-installed-in-linux-from-commandline/

```
$ ls /usr/bin/*session
/usr/bin/byobu-select-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session      /usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session

$ type Xorg
Xorg is /usr/bin/Xorg

$ ls /usr/share/xsessions/
ubuntu.desktop

$ dpkg -l | grep xserver
ii  x11-xserver-utils                                           7.7+8                             amd64        X server utilities
ii  xserver-common                                              2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2        all          common files used by various X servers
ii  xserver-xephyr                                              2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2        amd64        nested X server
ii  xserver-xorg                                                1:7.7+19ubuntu14                  amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                                           2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2        amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all                                      1:7.7+19ubuntu14                  amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput                                 0.29.0-1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom                                    1:0.39.0-0ubuntu1                 amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy                                         2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2        amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                                      1:7.7+19ubuntu14                  amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                                   19.1.0-1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                                      1:19.1.0-1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                                    1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1                  amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                                    2:2.99.917+git20200226-1          amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                                  1:1.0.16-1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                                      0.1.5+git20200331-1               amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                                   1:19.1.0-1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                                     1:2.4.0-2                         amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                                   1:13.3.0-3                        amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

How can I get rid of all desktop-related packages and drivers? This is a headless machine, no need to load it with unnecessary desktop applications.

Again, this is Ubuntu20.04LTS (was CL-only earlier).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to install `tasksel` and using that to remove `ubuntu-desktop`:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install tasksel -y
tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Sometimes `tasksel remove` will return errors, you can check unsatisfied dependencies via:

```bash
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

As to why it has happened in the first place, I have no idea.